# Mixed content message when all looks to be over SSL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iis, ssl, https

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 app, upgraded from MVC3, to 4, and now to 5.

I deployed it to an internal IIS 7.5 server that has a wildcard cert on it.  The CA is an enterprise trusted root by domain group policy.

When I load my site, I'm expecting a nice green lock icon in Google Chrome, but instead I get:

[image: Screen shot of error]

In the Chrome developer tools, on the Network screen, I'm looking at all the resources that were collected by the browser.  Each one is going over HTTPS.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like something weird happened in Chrome.  I shut down all my browser windows, and when I started the site back up again, all was well and I got my green lock icon.